# object animation / keyframe moving wrong object?

Tags: animation, objects, blender-internal-render-engine, keyframes

I'm animating a sliding door. I have two window panes and one frame.  They are not parented to each other and I have separated them from a single object. It is three total objects.  I cleared all location, applied locations to all three as well.

However, when I add a location keyframe to just ONE door to swing open, the whole frame moves along with that door object. I did NOT keyframe the frame object. Why are these other objects moving when I specifically key framed a totally different object for location change?

I have uploaded my blend file to google drive:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzM6QGd0jb8YU0hiUTRVMS1BVmc/view?usp=sharing

The sliding door model is on layer 2 and i have attempted to make an animation in dope sheet called "sliding_door_open".  All I do is grab the left door, move it -2 direction on the X axis and insert location key frame, etc.

Comment: Have you checked the animation curves after selecting all objects, and also constraints or hooks on those objects? If you can't sort it out checking most common places, nobody can't help you without having the file, I guess.

Comment: I have checked those things and still not sure why. I have uploaded a link to the .blend file.

Comment: In that file, I see only one door sliding... as expected. ?

Comment: I'm unable to make both doors swing.. everytime i add keyframes the whole frame moves or other "wierdness" happens

Comment: ok, but is not clear what you wish to achieve: there are 2 doors. should they slide  together in opposite directions, so to free the door passage? Or how?

Comment: Yes should slide opposite... freeing the passage like regular sliding doors you see everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'll write an answer so to be able to attach images and files.

As I wrote in the comments above, I tried your file and it just is wrongly keyframed, it has no other weird problems, to me.

What you have to do is reset the keyframes for the two sliding doors, and I'll show you how, below.

Your file hase several shapes, so I created a new empty blender file, and then just imported (appended) the three relevant objects from your file (cube.003, cube.004, cube.005), and since also their existing keyframes were imported, I use this as a starting point to reset animation for the sliding doors, as desired. But you should be able to use your file (I tried and it works also there).

This is what I imported (appended) from your file: there is a keyframe for the left door but is moving in the wrong direction (it goes to the right)

[image]

To restart from scratch, first I've deleted all existing keyframes for the door setup:

[image]

Then, at frame 1 I selected both doors, and inserted a keyframe there, for the starting position

[image]

This is what you get after (I also moved to frame 21)

[image]

Then I selected the left door and moved it X -2

[image]

And moved the right door to X +2

[image]

This is the desired final position, at the frame 21 so, let's add a keyframe for both selected doors:

[image]

The result is shown in the f-curve editor:

[image]

I'll add the file here for your reference:
[image]

Let me know if there something that needs to be explained more.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation above! Do these animations go to the same animation action in action editor if I need to export them in, lets say fbx format or something?